# How can I break up my model in to two lists in rails admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rails-admin

I have model Task with boolean field done. In rails admin it shown in table with fields. How can i break up this table in two lists. In first list will be only tasks with done=true. In second with done=false. Have any ideas?

Comment: Please show some code: what you've tried, what you expected.  Also, as far as I know, there is no stock rails admin; is this a gem?  If you want help with this project, you will need to meet the community halfway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add these scopes to Task model:

```
scope :done, -> { where done: true }
scope :todo, -> { where done: false }
```

Then you can call the scope accordingly:
Task.done or Task.todo

and shows the tasks in your lists.

Unless you are looking for an HTML/CSS solution and how to display your lists.

Comment: may be stupid question, bun how can I call the scope correctly?

Comment: I can use something like this?  config.model Task do
  field :players do
    associated_collection_cache_all false 
    associated_collection_scope do
      task = bindings[:object]
      Proc.new { |scope|
        scope = scope.where(done: task.done) if task.present?
        scope = scope. 
      }
    end
  end
end

Comment: Task.done will return all the tasks with 'done' equals to true. Is it what you are asking?

Comment: Yes. It's one table with my tasks in rails admin. I need to do two tables with doned tasks in first and not donned tasks in second

Comment: Did you add the two scopes inside your Task model?
Task.done contains an array with the doned tasks and Task.todo contains an array with the not doned tasks.

Then you can do something like this in your controller: 
\@done = Task.done
\@todo = Task.todo

And inside your views:
\@done.each{|task| puts task}
\@todo.each{|task| puts task}

Comment: Yes bun rails_admin do not generate controllers and vies it add only config file. I think i should to do something there.

Comment: You can try what you said in your second comment but you will need to remove 'field :players' (unless your tasks are associated with the players table) and also remove 'associated_collection_cache_all' and 'associated_collection_scope'

Comment: thank you. I done the scopes how in your comment and add to the config that RailsAdmin.config do |config|\n
  config.model Team do\n
    list do\n
      scopes [:done, :todo, nil]\n
    end\n
  end\n
end\n And all works)

Comment: No problem. Why did you accept the other answer as the best? Did it resolve your issue?

Comment: sorry miss click

Answer (score 0):

You can do these in your Task model

```
scope :completed_task, -> { where(done: true) }
scope :incomplete_task, -> { where(done: false) }
```